# How to solve an equation in R for multiple values and save the results in an object?

Tags: r, function, equation

I'm very new to R, and I have an equation that's something like this:

(1/(1+**X**)) - (1/(3)) * (1/(1+**X**))^(3) - (1/3)(1-***t***)^(1.4) = 0

Where X is a numeric vector (object?) containing 200 values. I want to solve this equation for each X value, and therefore get 200 values of t stored. How would I approach something like that?

I've tried the function function to no avail

```
function(t) {(1/(1+X)) - (1/(3)) * (1/(1+X))^(3) - (1/3)(1-t)^(1.4) = 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `Y = 1/(1+X)`. Then your function is a polynomial of degree 3 in the variable `Y`:

```
- 1/3 * Y^3 + Y - (1-t)^1.4 / 3
```

So you can solve your equation with the `polyroot` function (see `?polyroot`):

```
t <- 0.5
polyroot(c(-(1-t)^1.4 / 3, 1, 0, -1/3))
# 0.1269924-0i -1.7920519+0i  1.6650595+0i
```

There are three roots in general. Note that `polyroot` always returns complex numbers, even if the solutions are real numbers (imaginary part zero).

This gives the values of `Y`. You want the values of `X`, then do:

```
Y <- polyroot(c(-(1-t)^1.4 / 3, 1, 0, -1/3))
X <- (1 - Y) / Y
```

---

### EDIT

If `t` is the unknown value, you just have to isolate it. This gives:

```
f <- function(X){
  1 - (-(1/(1+X))^3 + 3*(1/(1+X)))^(1/1.4)
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, but I want 200 values of t that result from solving that particular equation for my vector X, which has 200 values. I don't know how to possibly code it. How is your answer vectorial?

Comment: Ah ok, wait a minute please.

Comment: Ok, see my edit please.